# Add object to ArrayList at specified index

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I think it's a fairly simple question, but I can't figure out how to do this properly.

I've got an empty arraylist:

```
ArrayList<object> list = new ArrayList<object>();
```

I've got some objects In which I want to add object and each object has to be at a certain position. It is necessary however that they can be added in each possible order. When I try this, it doesn't work and I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
list.add(1, object1)
list.add(3, object3)
list.add(2, object2)
```

What I have tried is filling the `ArrayList` with `null` and then doing the above. It works, but I think it's a horrible solution. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You get an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the list is empty and you cannot access a list position that doesn't exist...

Comment: Is there a way to create that position without filling the list with null objects? To me it seems like it's a really weird solution.

Comment: I don't think so... If you need to add the objects in a random order, you would have to look for another way of doing it.. For example with a typical array: 'Object[]' and then you shouldn't have to fill it, just initialize

Comment: @Maethortje it is not really a weird problem. Look up sparse lists, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SparseArrays-ManipulatingLists.html seems a good article. In Java though, a Map with index as key might be the easiest approach.

Comment: @Vic Even when i declare an arraylist with a size? you still can't access the index? I just got this kinda error also outofbounds, so the reason is the same? thanks

Comment: @Pan Even if you declare the size.. It just does not initialize the list, but declare how many space you want to reserve in memory.. As I see it, a list is an array of elements which also has a pointer to the next element. If you try to add an element into the third position when you have the second empty (or null) you have no pointer to help you know it is the third element..: 1->2->3 is OK, but 1->*->3 here you have a problem...

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
list.add(1, object1)
list.add(2, object3)
list.add(2, object2)
```

After you add object2 to position 2, it will move object3 to position 3.

If you want object3 to be at position3 all the time I'd suggest you use a HashMap with position as key and object as a value.

Comment: A hashmap would indeed be able to solve this problem. I think I'll go for that one since it doesn't seem like I can add something at location 3 when there is no object at location 2.

Comment: short but most Answer. Others are just on wrong track

Comment: A constructive logic!

Answer (score 37):

You can use Array of objects and convert it to ArrayList-

```
Object[] array= new Object[10];
array[0]="1";
array[3]= "3";
array[2]="2";
array[7]="7";

List<Object> list= Arrays.asList(array);
```

ArrayList will be- [1, null, 2, 3, null, null, null, 7, null, null]

Comment: One drawback is you have to know size in advance.

Answer (score 17):

If that's the case then why don't you consider using a regular Array, initialize the capacity and put objects at the index you want.

```
Object[] list = new Object[10];

list[0] = object1;
list[2] = object3;
list[1] = object2;
```

Comment: You initalize the capacity, but not the size of the 'ArrayList'. The size is defined as number of elements, and when the index is > size the exception comes...

Comment: @Vic, I misread the question at first, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: I initialized the capacity at 10, but I still get an IndexOutOfBoundsExceptopn when adding an object. Same with changing the capacity with ensureCapacity. Only thing that works is filling with null at the moment...

Comment: @Maethortje Look for the difference between "size" and "capacity"... The exception comes when the index is > the size, not when it is > capacity.....

Comment: As the guys mentioned, you are adding an object at index 3, while the size of the list is still 1. That's not possible. Adding at specific index is allowed as long as this index is inside the boundaries of the list, for example if your list has 3 objects, you cannot add an object at index 100.

Comment: @medopal While my application is running, new objects can be created which have to be added. That's why I chose for a list.

Comment: Not exactly what J.Maes was looking for, but i found this answer to be a good suggestion either way. If you do happen to know the size of your list - array trumps array list in this case. Thanks Medopal, +1 !

Answer (score 15):

You could also override ArrayList to insert nulls between your size and the element you want to add.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArrayListAnySize<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element){
        if(index >= 0 && index <= size()){
            super.add(index, element);
            return;
        }
        int insertNulls = index - size();
        for(int i = 0; i < insertNulls; i++){
            super.add(null);
        }
        super.add(element);
    }
}
```

Then you can add at any point in the ArrayList.  For example, this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayListAnySize<String> a = new ArrayListAnySize<>();
    a.add("zero");
    a.add("one");
    a.add("two");
    a.add(5,"five");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i+": "+a.get(i));
    }
}
```

yields this result from the console:

0: zero

1: one

2: two

3: null

4: null

5: five

Comment: Attention! If you put at the end a.add(3, "three");, the fifth element will be pushed forward. You will have: "6: five"

Answer (score 11):

I draw your attention to the [`ArrayList.add` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), which says it throws    `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range (`index < 0 || index > size()`)

Check the `size()` of your list before you call `list.add(1, object1)`

Comment: You are right @Hemal,  @Maethortje Why dont you check the size of the list before you add the element to the list ? check if the position you are trying to add is less than the size of the list, if not then you can just do a normal `list.add("element");`

Comment: As i understand it, the "problem" is to add the element at position 3 even if there is not an element in position 2...

Comment: @Vis that is a sparse list -- see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to populate the empty indexes with nulls.

```
while (arraylist.size() < position)
{
     arraylist.add(null);
}

arraylist.add(position, object);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Maethortje 

The problem here is java creates an empty list when you called new ArrayList and
```

while trying to add an element at specified position you got IndexOutOfBound ,
so the list should have some elements at their position.

Please try following

```
/*
  Add an element to specified index of Java ArrayList Example
  This Java Example shows how to add an element at specified index of java
  ArrayList object using add method.
*/

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddElementToSpecifiedIndexArrayListExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create an ArrayList object
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    //Add elements to Arraylist
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");

    /*
      To add an element at the specified index of ArrayList use
      void add(int index, Object obj) method.
      This method inserts the specified element at the specified index in the
      ArrayList.  
    */
    arrayList.add(1,"INSERTED ELEMENT");

    /*
      Please note that add method DOES NOT overwrites the element previously
      at the specified index in the list. It shifts the elements to right side
      and increasing the list size by 1.
    */

    System.out.println("ArrayList contains...");
    //display elements of ArrayList
    for(int index=0; index < arrayList.size(); index++)
      System.out.println(arrayList.get(index));

  }
}

/*
Output would be
ArrayList contains...
1
INSERTED ELEMENT
2
3

*/
```

Comment: I understand the problem which causes my error. It seems like I have to add objects to the subsequent positions before I can add an object to that position. The moment I'm adding, I'm not disposing of all the objects I want to add. Do you think adding null objects is a proper solution then?

Comment: @Maethortje It wont be very fair to do this, as its just a hack :)

Comment: you need to remove the code sample quotes from the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

How about this little `while` loop as a solution?

```
private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

private void addObject(int i, Object object) {
    while(list.size() < i) {
        list.add(list.size(), null);
    }
    list.add(i, object);
}
....

addObject(1, object1)
addObject(3, object3)
addObject(2, object2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
list.add(list.size(), new Object());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution from medopal is what you are looking for.

But just another alternative solution is to use a HashMap and use the key (Integer) to store positions.

This way you won't need to populate it with nulls etc initially, just stick the position and the object in the map as you go along. You can write a couple of lines at the end to convert it to a List if you need it that way.

Comment: Isn't TreeMap is better since ordered by keys?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but hopefully can still be useful to someone.

2 steps to adding items to a specific position in an `ArrayList`

1. `add` null items to a specific index in an `ArrayList`
2. Then `set` the positions as and when required.

   ```
       list = new ArrayList();//Initialise the ArrayList
   for (Integer i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
       list.add(i, null); //"Add" all positions to null
   }
      // "Set" Items
       list.set(position, SomeObject);
   ```

This way you don't have redundant items in the `ArrayList` i.e. if you were to add items such as,

```
list = new ArrayList(mItems.size());    
list.add(position, SomeObject);
```

This would **not** overwrite existing items in the position merely, shifting existing ones to the right by one - so you have an ArrayList with twice as many indicies.

Answer (score 1):

You should set instead of add to replace existing value at index.

```
list.add(1, object1)
list.add(2, object3)
list.set(2, object2)
```

List will contain  [object1,object2]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to add an item at a position, then the list size must be more than the position.

`add(2, item)`: this syntax means, move the old item at position 2 to next index and add the item at 2nd position.

If there is no item in 2nd position, then this will not work, It'll throw an exception.

That means if you want to **add** something in `position 2,`

your **list size** must be at least `(2 + 1) =3,` so the items are available at `0,1,2 Position.`

in that way it is ensured that the position 2 is accessed safely and there would be no exception.

Comment: i'm just passing by when i notified your answer... actually, index must be **lower or equal** than the real length of the list at the moment we are inserting new item.   
exhample: list size is 2: adding in index 2 will work.  adding in index 3 will throw an exception. (It was tested)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android flavor of Java, might I suggest using a [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html). It's a more memory efficient mapping of integers to objects and easier to iterate over than a Map