# Adding item to the quizQuestion ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

Hey guys so I have the method

```
public void addQuestion(Question question)
{

}
```

I have created an `ArrayList` in the class section

```
private ArrayList<Question> quizQuestion;
```

and I have initialised the `ArrayList` in the constructor by typing

```
quizQuestion = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

What do I type in the method above so I can add questions to the Question `ArrayList`. :)

Comment: `quizQuestion.add(question);`. Even if you had no idea about it, you could simply guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add object to arraylist at specified index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index)

Comment: There is no close reason, but the answer is so easy that you should delete the question or be ashamed of yourself the rest of your life.

Comment: @SagarPudi: It's not a duplicate, but you should downvote because "it does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addQuestion(Question question)
{
     quizQuestion.add(question);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addQuestion(Question question)
{
     quizQuestion.add(question);
}
```

Comment: Possible (exact) duplicate of previous answer :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun
I didn't see the answer while posting

Comment: Race condition, never mind lol . The question is too trivial anyway :p

Comment: @MarounMaroun there aren't many possibile answers here to be honest :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you really want :)

but if you just want to add parameter Question to arraylist quizQuestion

```
quizQuestion.add(question);
```

I hope this helps...

Keep Leanrning :)