# Android final variable is no variable?

Tags: android, arraylist, final

I have a void like this:

```
public static void checkStateSignal(final int counter) {
    for (int l = 0; l < counter; l += 10) {
        if (counter - l < 9) {

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                ArraySignal.LoggerStatus.get(counter) = separated[1];
                }
            },150);
        } 
    }
}
```

in which `ArraySignal` is a class and `Loggerstatus` is an `Arraylist`. I get an error on

```
ArraySignal.LoggerStatus.get(counter) = separated[1];
```

which is variable expected. So for some reason a final variable is not a variable and `ArrayList.get` doesn't want to get at a value position instead of a variable position which seems very illogical to me since you can get at a constant. Am i missing something? Also a solution for the problem would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the accesor .get(index) for the ArrayList and that return a value, you need to use the .add(index,elem) to add an element at the given position. Check this link to look around [Add object to ArrayList at specified index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index)

Comment: What i'm trying to do is setting the string in that index to a certain value. not adding a new one seems kind of redundant to add and then remove the previous one

Comment: oh, apparently there's a set function which I can use to set that String. Didn't know that. Was searching in the wrong direction, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new class:

```
Class NewRunnable extends Runnable
{
   public int counter;
   public NewRunnable(int _counter)
   {
       counter = _counter;
       super();
   }
}
```

and then use that in your code like:

```
handler.postDelayed(new NewRunnable(counter) {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                String[] separated;
                ArraySignal.LoggerStatus.get(counter) = separated[1];
                }
            },150);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArraySignal.LoggerStatus.get(counter) = separated[1]
```

I think the issue is, you are trying to set value to a function