# Adding a new item to an existing index while retaining existing items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I add an item to a `RecyclerView` at an index that currently has an item and retain any items that exist below it in stacking order?  For example, if I have this list:

> item = 0, item 1, item 2, ...

I want to insert an item into an existing index but without replacing the original value:

> item = 0, **item A**, item 1, item 2, ...

The code I have used so far is:

```
public void addRecyclerObject(int position, Object recyclerObject) {
   recyclerObjects.add(position, recyclerObject);
   notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

However, when I use execute the above code, the RecyclerView renders as such:

> item = 0, **item A**, item 2, ...

`item 1` is completely removed and replaced with another value. How can I insert another item without replacing an existing value? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a `List` to generate the items within the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `List` to intialise the items in your `RecyclerView`, you can easily insert it into an existing index and the original item stored in that location is moved without being replaced. For example:

```
list.add(1, "String 1")
list.add(2, "String 2")
list.add(2, "String 3")
```

`String1` is inserted normally. `String2` is inserted into the second position. `String3` is also inserted into the second position, pushing `String2` into the third position and altering the rest of the data set as well. If you need more help, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index) post. Tell me how you go.