# How to add something to your already sorted array and have it stay sorted without using sort array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a list of 9 Pizza toppings that are already sorted in array that's length is 15. The remaining 6 spaces are filled with `"zzz"`.

`toppings =new String[] {"pepperoni","sausage","extracheese","peppers","onions","mushrooms","ham","ground beef","anchovies","zzz","zzz","zzz","zzz","zzz","zzz"};`

I am writing an `addTopping` method that will replace one of the `zzz`'s with an actual topping.

`public boolean addTopping(String top)`

I am having trouble adding this extra topping while keeping the array sorted. Please keep in mind I am only in high school Computer Science AP, so nothing too advance please.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please post what you have tried and explain why it has not worked

Comment: The array you've shown isn't sorted at all, so what is your definition of "keeping the array sorted"?

Comment: By "keeping the array sorted", do you mean simply that you want the new topping to replace the first `"zzz"`,  without altering the positions of the existing toppings?

Comment: I used array.sort to sort the array that is shown, but I am not supposed to use array.sort after adding the extra topping.

Comment: I just want to replace a "zzz" with a topping and then put into the right postion in the array, where the array will still be sorted.]

Comment: Hint: Find the place to insert the element, then move elements after the insertion point to make hole.

Comment: ...and just throw away the last `"zzz"`.  Also be sure to check that you have a `"zzz"` to throw away if you don't want to shove a "real" item off the end!

Comment: It's just confusing for me how do that without making a new array or without messing up the values in my current array. Like if I change the position of toppings[i] to toppings[i+1], then the topping previously at i + 1 is gone and I can't move it to the next position.

Comment: Work the other direction, from **higher to lower** indices.  Start with `i` at `toppings.length-1` and move `toppings[i-1]` to `toppings[i]`.  That way you don't step on any entries that you haven't moved yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method for calling to index of an element in order to add on the first element is found, this is an answer:

```
public void addTopping(String top) {
    int index = indexOf(toppings, "zzz");
    if (index != -1) {
        toppings[index] = top;
    }
}

public int indexOf(String[] elementData, String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementData.length; i++) {
            if (elementData[i] == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementData.length; i++) {
            if (string.equals(elementData[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("pepperoni");
    list.add("sausage");
    list.add("extracheese");
    list.add("peppers");
    list.add("onions");
    list.add("mushrooms");
    list.add("ham");
    list.add("ground beef");
    list.add("anchovies");
    list.add("zzz");
    list.add("zzz");
    list.add("zzz");
    list.add("zzz");
    list.add("zzz");
    list.add("zzz");

    String r="olive";
    Collections.sort(list);
    int s= list.size();
    for( int i=0; i< s ; i++){
        System.out.println(list.size());
        if(list.get(i).compareTo(r) == 1){
            list.add(i,r);
            break;
        }
    }
    for( int i=0; i< s ; i++){


        if(list.get(i).equals("zzz")){
            list.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    for( int i=0; i< list.size() ; i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused on what the line  `list.add(i,r);` is doing.

Comment: here i is the index of the array and r is the new topping...the list.add(i,r); is adding the r (new topping) in that index i.And the rest of the elements of the arraylist will automatically adjust their position.like "pepperoni" was in index 6. after adding the olive in index 6,"pepperoni" will have the new position index 6+1=7. so on for the rest of the elements.  let me know if you need more explanation. this link might help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index