# How to add element at a specific position in ArrayList while sorting using Arraylist?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to add an integer value at a specific position in an ArrayList but after doing so it pushes at last element to its next index, as i am doing sorting i do not want it to happen. Help me with a snippet of code to write bubble sort using ArrayList.

My code

```
void bubble_sorting(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    int swap;
    for(int i=0;i<5-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5-i-1;j++){
            if(arr.get(j)>arr.get(j+1)){
                swap = arr.get(j);
                arr.add(j,arr.get(j+1));
                arr.add(j+1,swap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after passing ArrayList [23,54,67,4,5]

I get this as output:
[4, 23, 23, 4, 54, 54, 4, 67, 67, 4, 5]

Comment: A quick look at the Javadoc for array list would help you out - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.add()` is wrong.  This **inserts** an element, not replaces it.  Read the Java doc, and I think the method you want is `.set()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add object to ArrayList at specified index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index)

Comment: @markspace Thank you..and sorry to bother you all for my foolishness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Javadocs for the ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class, there are some methods that will be helpful for you. I'd take a look at the set method!